# How to migrate from BMC Remedy and AccuRev to JIRA and AccuRev?

Tags: migration, jira, accurev, remedy

I am gathering information on what it takes to migrate from BMC Remedy and AccuRev to JIRA and AccuRev; and I would like to hear experiences from anyone who has done it and opinions from anyone who knows how to do it.

I found out that Borland has a bidirectional plugin for AccuRev and JIRA - http://www.borland.com/en-GB/Products/Change-Management/AccuSync/Integration .

How can I best migrate from BMC Remedy to JIRA?

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are comparing a development environment to a project management system I am going to assume that you have a project management application developed in Remedy.

As such the process of migrating would be consistent regardless of what you are migrating.

You have to identify the fields in the new application that need to be filled in and then what fields in the current system are going to be used to populate them.

Once that document is made then you just have to export the information from your source and import it into your destination.

Personally, if you are able to do Remedy development, I would consume Jira webservices and build the migration steps in Remedy so that you don't have to perform the extra steps.

I hope this helps.